pollEnrich is loading file in memory and causing heap error in EKS deployment
We have an app which consumes message from SQS and download file from s3 to filesystem based on sqs message.
We are using apache camel to poll SQS message queue and enrich and then download file to filesystem
It was working fine in ECS and when migrating to EKS, we are seeing issues with large files (> 1GB).
sample code
.log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Before enriching")
.pollEnrich().simple("S3 bucket url").cacheSize(-1).aggregationStrategy(new HeadersCopyAggregationStrategy())
.log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Finished Enriching File")


HeadersCopyAggregationStrategy Class is to copy header values as pollEnrich is removing header values
We are seeing log message "Before enriching" and then out of memory error for file size greater than 1 GB.
Code is working fine for smaller files (50MB or 200MB) in EKS

apache-camel version: 4.4.0
Deployment Infra: Amazon EKS
Heap memory configured: 2GB
No of threads: 10

Error:
2024-04-04 09:42:49.999 ERROR 26 --- [Camel (camel-1) thread #4 - aws2-s3://arn:aws:s3:::bucketname] [CID:] o.a.camel.support.ScheduledPollConsumer  : Error occurred during running scheduled task on: aws2-s3://arn:aws:s3:::bucketname?amazonS3Client=%23amazonS3Client&autoCreateBucket=false&prefix=fullfilepath&sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle=true, due: Java heap space. This exception is ignored and the task will run again on next poll.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3537)
at java.base/java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:100)
at java.base/java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:130)
at software.amazon.awssdk.utils.IoUtils.toByteArray(IoUtils.java:48)
at org.apache.camel.component.aws2.s3.AWS2S3Consumer.createExchange(AWS2S3Consumer.java:390)
at org.apache.camel.component.aws2.s3.AWS2S3Consumer.createExchange(AWS2S3Consumer.java:375)
at org.apache.camel.component.aws2.s3.AWS2S3Consumer.createExchanges(AWS2S3Consumer.java:224)
at org.apache.camel.component.aws2.s3.AWS2S3Consumer.poll(AWS2S3Consumer.java:161)
at org.apache.camel.support.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:204)
at org.apache.camel.support.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:118)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Any one faced similar issue?
Thanks

can you add the error message?

Updated Error in question

Ideally PollEnrich should not load file , but looks like pollEnrich is loading actual file to  memory and causing issue. i am not seeing "Finished Enriching File" message. Looks like pollEnrich is making an S3api call and downloading the file

If the message does not fit in memory you can try to spool it to disk. This can be configured in camel see documentation
Springboot
add
camel.springboot.stream-caching-spool-enabled=true
camel.springboot.stream-caching-spool-threshold=20971520

to your properties to set spooling for messages above 20MB. Feel free to adjust the value, but this can be reasonable start.
Manual config
context.getStreamCachingStrategy().setSpoolEnabled(true);
context.getStreamCachingStrategy().setSpoolThreshold(20 * 1024 * 1024);

and then
context.setStreamCaching(true);


Steaming is working but
pollEnrich pulling file from s3 to camel-spool directory and once file is pulled, then it copying to required folder. this is due to code in new AWS2S3Consumer.java which  gets ResponseInputStream s3Object.

In camel 3.2.0 , pollEnrich will only get file handle instead of entire file content.
